# Checking for existing records on database wen i call web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity

I am calling a web api and saving the records on the database through the controller, i want each time im calling the api to check if the record exists in the database if yes then dont save, if not then save.

```
 var client = new WebClient();
        var text = client.DownloadString("https://www.test.com/api/all-users?name=testusername%20&pass=334432");
        var wclients = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(text);
        List<apicli> list1 = new List<apicli>();
        var clie = new apicli();


        if (wclients.message == "success")
        {
            var data = wclients.data;
            //var account = wclients.account;
            ViewBag.test = data;

            foreach(var item in ViewBag.test)
            {

                clie.Email = item.email;
                clie.Name = item.name;
                clie.Aff = item.affiliated_id;

                foreach(var item1 in @item.account.real)
                {
                    clie.Login = item1.login;
                    clie.password = item1.pass;

                }
                list1.Add(clie);
                db.apiclis.AddRange(list1);
                db.SaveChanges();
            };
        }
```

Comment: This shouldn't be a task for the client side but for the receiving api side. The api should return to you with an error if the duplicate exists and you should handle the error accordingly. A part from the consideration about the logic I also would underline the fact that to test the existence of the record you need two calls instead of one.

Comment: i can not modify the the api so the only way to do it its through the client side.i need to check with my local database if a record exists or not.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume you need something like this, although you need to check what is the unique id of each record:

```
 foreach(var item in data){
            var c = new apicli  {
                Email = item.email,
                Name = item.name,
                Aff = item.affiliated_id
                Login = item.account.real.LastOrDefault()?login??"",
                Login = item.account.real.LastOrDefault()?pass??""
            }
            if(!db.apiclis.Any(a => a.Email == c.Email && a.Name == c.Name && a.Aff == c.Aff)){
                db.apiclis.Add(c);
            }
        }
```

Here I assume that email+name+aff = unique identificator.